# adding word to a field common to all records in a file

Tags: shell, unix

I want to add a word to field 1 of a file separated by space,for example

My file,containing two fields:

```
apple:fruit:tree
orange:fruit:tree
mango:fruit:tree
brinjal:vegetable:plant
potato:vegetable:root
```

now I want to add word "family" separated by space to the field 1.

Therefore, the resultant file should look some thing like this

```
apple family:fruit:tree
orange family:fruit:tree
mango family:fruit:tree
brinjal family:vegetable:plant
potato family:vegetable:root
```

Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can sed:

```
sed 's/:/ family:/' yourfile.txt
```

This will replace any `:` with `family:` which achieves the desired result. You might have to adjust the regular expression though, in case `:` also appears elsewhere in the text.

**Update:** I am not sure what you want with *I want to add a word "active" to field 1 of a file separated by space* as you give no example for that.

**Update 2:**
It will only replace the first occurrence of `:`. However, if you want to replace something in the middle, you just have to *capture* the data before the delimiter:

```
sed 's/^\(.*:.*\):/\1 family:/' test.txt
```

This example adds `family` before the third field. `\(.*:.*\)` captures the characters before and after the first `:` (i.e. the values of the first and second field). The following `:` will be replaced by this characters (`\1` is referring to the first capture group) followed by `family:`. The rest of the line stays untouched.

Comment: @Kling tankq ,but what if file contains 3 fields and i want to add "family" in the first field for example  potato:vegetable:root, how can i solve dis

Comment: @Shruti: Fleix's current solution will work even then as he is not doing the replacement globally.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk

```
$ awk -F":" '{$1=$1" family"}1' OFS=":" file
apple family:fruit:tree
orange family:fruit:tree
mango family:fruit:tree
brinjal family:vegetable:plant
potato family:vegetable:root
```

If you want to add to 2nd field, just do `$2=$2" family"`. Its easier than creating regex such as by using sed.

Now may i redirect you to [awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html) to learn about awk. Try to do it yourself next time.